# Manual checkpoint from Flink stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it possible to trigger checkpoint from Flink streaming job?

My use case is that: I have two streams R and S to join with tumbling time windows. The source is Kafka. I use event time processing and BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator to make sure events from two streams end up in the same window.

The problem is my states are large and a regular periodic checkpoint takes too much time sometimes. At first, I wanted to disable checkpointing and rely on Kafka offset. But out of orderness means I have already some data in future windows from current offset. So I need checkpointing.

If it was possible to trigger checkpoints after a window gets cleaned instead of periodic ones it would be more efficient. Maybe at evictAfter method.

Does that make sense and is it possible? IF not I'd appreciate a work around.

Comment: in the Flink environment you can try to reduce the checkpoint interval. Have you seen 1.2 release notes? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/stream/checkpointing.html#state-checkpoints-in-iterative-jobs

Comment: I don't see how that helps. Even if I take checkppints less frequently, they are still going to be large. I want to trigger checkpoints when I have least amount of events in operators for efficiency.

Comment: _more_ frequently. Reducing the interval would make the checkpoints smaller

Answer (score 1):

Seems the issue here is checkpoint efficiency.   Consider using the RocksDB state backend with incremental checkpoints, discussed in the docs under [Debugging and Tuning Checkpoints and Large State](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/large_state_tuning.html#tuning-rocksdb).